# dynamically call same named function with different return type

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visual-c++, clr

I have a situation here...
I want to design a Factory where I can call a function with same name and no parameters but return different data Types. Based on the SubClassName I need to instantiate the Object.

Need help or lead on any design pattern to follow?

EDIT:
An abstract pseudo code...

```
class parent{
 public:
  virtual string getName() = 0;
  //some virtual function.. not sure how to design. As the return type is dynamic.
  *** getValue(){}
};
class A : public parent{
  int x;
 public:
  virtual string getName(){ return "A";}
  virtual int getValue(){retun x;}
};
class B : public parent{
  string s;
 public:
  virtual string getName(){ return "B";}
  virtual string getValue(){ return s;}
};

void main(){
  string callingClass = "B";
  parent * arrayPtrs[2];
  arrayPtrs[0] = new A;
  arrayPtrs[1] = new B;

  for (loop through array, through iterator i){
  if(arrayPtrs[i]->getName == callingClass ){
     cout<<arrayPtrs[i]->getValue;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: something like `template<class T> class base { T function(); }` and `class Float : base<float> { ... }` or `class Integer : base <int> { ... }`?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. You cannot overload based on return type, so you cannot have two functions that are the same only differ only by return type (at least not in the same namespace)

Comment: updated my question with an abstract code snippet.Sorry if I had not asked a clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ a function can only have one return type at a time, and you cannot change that dynamically.
However - as suggested by @mch - you can use template specializations. Keep in mind though, that this method is not *dynamic*. Your functions will be generated at *compile time*.

If I understood your question correctly, maybe this can be of help.

```
class MyObject1
{
    //...
};
class MyObject2
{
    //...
};

template<typename T>
struct Factory
{
    constexpr static T gen();
};

template<>
struct Factory<MyObject1>
{
    constexpr static MyObject1 gen()
    {
        return MyObject1(/*... whatever parameters you see fit ...*/);
    }
};

template<>
struct Factory<MyObject2>
{
    constexpr static MyObject2 gen()
    {
        return MyObject2(/*... whatever parameters you see fit ...*/);
    }
};


int main()
{
    auto myObj = Factory<MyObject1>::gen();
    return 0;
}
```

Although this method seems fairly useless to me. You could simply call the desired constructor instead of this.
But then again, I'm not sure if this is what you thought of. If I made any mistakes please feel free, to correct me. I'll try to edit my answer best as I can.

**EDIT:** 
To keep the virtual functionality too, the only way I can think of is type erasure: see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Erasure

The closest I could get to what you've asked for is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <any>


class parent {
public:
    // you can use this too but I think type checking is more handy
    // see in main function
    /* virtual std::string getName() const = 0; */

    virtual std::any getValue() const = 0;
};
class A : public parent {
public:
    typedef int value_type;

private:
    value_type x;
public:
    A(value_type x) :
        x(x)
    {}

    /* virtual std::string getName() const override { return "A"; } */
    virtual std::any getValue() const override
    { return this->x; }
};
class B : public parent {
public:
    typedef std::string value_type;

private:
    value_type s;

public:
    B(const value_type& s) :
        s(s)
    {}

    /* virtual std::string getName() const override { return "B"; } */
    virtual std::any getValue() const override
    { return this->s; }
};

int main(){
    using callingClass = A;
    parent* arrayPtrs[2];
    arrayPtrs[0] = new A(42);
    arrayPtrs[1] = new B("my string");

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(arrayPtrs) / sizeof(parent*); ++i)
    {
        // Note:
        // dynamic cast will return nullptr if $callingClass
        // is not a derived class
        if (dynamic_cast<callingClass*>(arrayPtrs[i]))
            std::cout << std::any_cast<callingClass::value_type>(arrayPtrs[i]->getValue()) << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I hope this one helps.

Note, that I used `dynamic_cast` to check the correct type. If you know a better solution, you can use that, too. But under these circumstances I couldn't think of any better.

**EDIT2:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>


class some
{
    using id = size_t;

    template<typename T>
    struct type { static void id() { } };

    template<typename T>
    static id type_id() { return reinterpret_cast<id>(&type<T>::id); }

    template<typename T>
    using decay = typename std::decay<T>::type;

    template<typename T>
    using none = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<some, T>::value>::type;

    struct base
    {
        virtual ~base() { }
        virtual bool is(id) const = 0;
        virtual base *copy() const = 0;
    } *p = nullptr;


    template<typename T>
    struct data : base, std::tuple<T>
    {
        using std::tuple<T>::tuple;

        T       &get()      & { return std::get<0>(*this); }
        T const &get() const& { return std::get<0>(*this); }

        bool is(id i) const override { return i == type_id<T>(); }
        base *copy()  const override { return new data{get()}; }
    };

    template<typename T>
    T &stat() { return static_cast<data<T>&>(*p).get(); }

    template<typename T>
    T const &stat() const { return static_cast<data<T> const&>(*p).get(); }

    template<typename T>
    T &dyn() { return dynamic_cast<data<T>&>(*p).get(); }

    template<typename T>
    T const &dyn() const { return dynamic_cast<data<T> const&>(*p).get(); }

public:
     some() { }
    ~some() { delete p; }

    some(some &&s)      : p{s.p} { s.p = nullptr; }
    some(some const &s) : p{s.p->copy()} { }

    template<typename T, typename U = decay<T>, typename = none<U>>
    some(T &&x) : p{new data<U>{std::forward<T>(x)}} { }

    some &operator=(some s) { swap(*this, s); return *this; }

    friend void swap(some &s, some &r) { std::swap(s.p, r.p); }

    void clear() { delete p; p = nullptr; }

    bool empty() const { return p; }

    template<typename T>
    bool is() const { return p ? p->is(type_id<T>()) : false; }

    template<typename T> T      &&_()     && { return std::move(stat<T>()); }
    template<typename T> T       &_()      & { return stat<T>(); }
    template<typename T> T const &_() const& { return stat<T>(); }

    template<typename T> T      &&cast()     && { return std::move(dyn<T>()); }
    template<typename T> T       &cast()      & { return dyn<T>(); }
    template<typename T> T const &cast() const& { return dyn<T>(); }

    template<typename T> operator T     &&()     && { return std::move(_<T>()); }
    template<typename T> operator T      &()      & { return _<T>(); }
    template<typename T> operator T const&() const& { return _<T>(); }
};


using any = some;


class parent {
public:
    // you can use this too but I think type checking is more handy
    /* virtual std::string getName() const = 0; */

    virtual any getValue() const = 0;
};
class A : public parent {
public:
    typedef int value_type;

private:
    value_type x;
public:
    A(value_type x) :
        x(x)
    {}

    /* virtual std::string getName() const override { return "A"; } */
    virtual any getValue() const override
    { return this->x; }
};
class B : public parent {
public:
    typedef std::string value_type;

private:
    value_type s;

public:
    B(const value_type& s) :
        s(s)
    {}

    /* virtual std::string getName() const override { return "B"; } */
    virtual any getValue() const override
    { return this->s; }
};

int main(){
    using callingClass = A;
    parent* arrayPtrs[2];
    arrayPtrs[0] = new A(42);
    arrayPtrs[1] = new B("my string");

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(arrayPtrs) / sizeof(parent*); ++i)
    {
        // Note:
        // dynamic cast will return nullptr if $callingClass
        // is not a derived class
        if (dynamic_cast<callingClass*>(arrayPtrs[i]))
            std::cout << arrayPtrs[i]->getValue()._<callingClass::value_type>() << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

This snipped is in case you cannot use C++17 features, and is based on:
[any class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47975/any-class-implementation)

Comment: Thanks @skyZip for the reply. But my question is little different. I don't know the ObjectType on main(). I updated my question with an abstract code snippet.

Comment: I edited my answer, in hope it will suit your needs. If something is not clear, please feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks again @SkyZip, kudos for researching again for me. But my project does not support C++ 17. I read somewhere std::any is from C++17. I am using VC++ 2017 15.9 v14.16. Can there be any other apart from std::any ?

Comment: Yes there is. You can implement the `any` class functionality yourself - or something like that - using only C++11 features. This link might come in handy: [any class implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47975/any-class-implementation).
I will edit my answer based on the code from this, for clarification on how it works.